# Converting MYSQLI TO PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

Hello I am trying to create a login system, and my skills in the back-end are extremely limited. I used a tutorial to create a database realising that all my php on my other pages used pdo where this tutorial is mysqli.

I have tried tinkering with this code to try and adapt it, however my tries have not been successful.

Really cheeky but much appreciated if somebody could edit the code to work with PDO :).

Many thanks

```
<?php
 try {
   $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=loginsytem', 'root', '');
   $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e->getName();
   die();
 }

 session_start();

 $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users');

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   incude_'dbh.inc.php';

   $uid = PDO::quote($conn, $_POST['uid']);
   $pwd = PDO::quote($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

   //Error Handlers
   //Check if inputs are empty

   if (empty($uid)) || empty($pwd)) {
     header("location: ../index.php?login=empty");
     exit();
   }
 }   else {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if ($resultCheck < 1) {
       header("location: ../index.php?login=error");
       exit();
     } else {
       if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         //de-hashing the password
         $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pdw']);
         if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
           header("location: ../index.php?login=error");
           exit();

         } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
           //Log in the user here
           $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
           $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
           header("location: ../index.php?login=success");
           exit();
         }
       }
     }
   }

   else {
   header("location: ../index.php?login=error");
   exit();
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: "if somebody could edit the code to work with PDO" that's not how Stack Overflow works. We're not here to write code for you. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.. Notice changes by comparing your code.. To learn PDO with MySQL, refer to this tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

```
<?php
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=loginsytem', 'root', '');
$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid=:uid");
     $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
     if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         //de-hashing the password
         $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pdw']);
         if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
             header("location: ../index.php?login=error");
             exit();
         }
         //Log in the user here
         $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
         $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
         header("location: ../index.php?login=success");
     }
}
```